# increase ram of smartphone using sd card

Tags: rooting, ram

Is it possible to increase ram using sd card by rohesoft ram expander after rooting? i have read it in an article
anyone tell me working method to create virtual ram in android phone.can i expand the size of ram of my smart phone by usingvsd card

Answer (score 0):

U r'nt increasing RAM, but adding SWAP as virtual memory. SWAP is memory management technique where OS is allocating data in block structures with same size - pages - for use in RAM. Inevitably, there is latency - from fastest to slowest - CPU registries, L cache, RAM, pages.
Think of SWAP as cache - a kind of a waiting room in ER. It's much faster to enter MD's office from waiting room than to come from home && enter when it's ur turn.
Regarding that particular app, I haven't experience - try it - but u can create SWAP from ADB shell if root privilege is accessible && busybox is present.
If u want to try creating SWAP from ADB shell, I suggest reading [thread on this fourm about this topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89028/creating-and-enabling-an-internal-storage-swap-partition-on-rooted-android-kitka), [article on MIUI](http://en.miui.com/thread-41301-1-1.html) and [XDA thread about init.d support](https://forum.xda-com/showpost.php?p=32716412&postcount=2). I was consulting that resources when making SWAP for ROM I made.

If u find u need more help, describe what ROM is used (everything else is already supposed), hence I'll make u a script with necessary files.